# Conditional Expectation: Orthogonal Projection in $L^2$

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces, expectation, orthogonality

Let $X \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ and $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ a sub-sigma-Algebra.

Then $E[X \mid \mathcal{F}]$ is the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.

I have some questions regarding this result.

1. We have restated this result as $E[(X-Z')^2] \geq E[(X-E[X \mid \mathcal{F})^2]$ for all $Z' \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Why is this the same?
2. What does it mean to have scalar product 0 in $L^2$?
3. General question concerning $X \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$. So this means that $X$ is a random variable with $E^P[|X|^2]^{1/2} = (\int_{\Omega} X(\omega)^2 dP(\omega))^{1/2} < \infty$ (which is Independent of the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, but depends on $P$) and is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. Is this true?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1. This is granted by a theorem by F. Riesz. But intuitively consider a point on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and try to project this point onto $x$-axis. Then point of projection must minimise distance from the point to $x$-axis - the same kind of thing applies but here the "distance" is characterised by integrals, which are inner products on $L^2$.

Answer (score 5):

The scalar product on $L^2$ is
$$\langle X, Y \rangle = E(XY) = \int_\Omega XY\, dP.$$

Note that if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $M$ is a closed subspace, the projection of $x$ onto $M$, $P_M(x)$, is the closest point in $M$ to $X$ in the $L^2$ norm.  This is a very basic property of Hilbert spaces.

The random variable $E(X|\mathcal{A})$ is $\mathcal{A}$ measurable and for all $Q\in\mathcal{A}$,
$$ \int_{Q} X\, dP = \int_Q E(X|\mathcal{A})\, dP.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a Little bit confused about the scalar product being $0$. This means that 

$E[(Z'-E[X \mid \mathcal{F}])(X-E[X \mid \mathcal{F}])]=0$? How does this relate to $E[(X-Z')^2] \geq E[(X-E[X\mid \mathcal{F}])^2]$?

Comment: And by the way: can you help me stating me the Pythagoras Theorem in $L^2$? It is claimed that something follows by the Pythagoras Theorem but I cannot find it in this form. Is it something like

$E[(X+Y)^2]=E[X^2] + E[Y^2]$, which holds when $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal? We used it to show $E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[((X-Z) + (Z-E[X]))^2] = E[(X-Z)^2] + E[(Z-E[X])^2]$ where $Z=E[X \mid \mathcal{F}]$, but I do not really get why $E[(X-Z)(Z-E[X])]=0$.